# How to quit my TT professorship job gracefully?

Tags: professorship, academic-life, quitting

I'm a TT assistant professor at a R1 school, and I just recently accepted an offer from a private company. I'm planning to talk with the department head and let him know and I was wondering if anyone has any thoughts how to approach this (with maybe examples if you have anything in mind) and quit gracefully ? Also do you think one month ahead is enough to let him know before the departure ?

Update: Ok, just wanted to share some update. I talked with the head today and something along this answer from @caleb-stanford worked really well.

For example: "While I have really enjoyed my time here, it's become increasingly clear to me that being in academia long-term is not the right fit. In addition, I have personal and family constraints that would require me to be away from for extended periods of time, and make having a more flexible work location a necessity for me in the future. I have nothing but positive things to say about . I'm sorry for the short notice; I'm letting you know as soon as possible, so that you can hopefully work to make plans accordingly for my departure."

Comment: That will cause them to scramble a bit, so the sooner the better. Does your chair know you were not happy? No need to sugarcoat it, you’ve made your decision. The rest is details like who takes over your students…

Comment: Why would you wait until 1 month before? It may be okay, but it would be more professional to tell them several months in advance, particularly if you have duties (especially teaching) that would need to be assigned to someone else.

Comment: Because I looked for a job 2 months ago and they offered to start in 6 weeks (norms of industry). But I'm planning to offer to the department, to keep teaching the class (bc the class is 6-9 pm for an online master degree) and change my appointment to something that would be fit for this plan. Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ultimately, there's no way to say it nicely. You're leaving, and that makes things difficult for them, so the best thing you can do is let them know as soon as possible. They will want to know why, so you have to be prepared with a *well-crafted reason* for your departure.

One crucial detail that I think is missing from your post: do you want to remain on good terms with the university, the department chair, and your colleagues, or are you leaving academia for good and have no interest in maintaining connections?

- In the former case, you have to be a bit careful. Firstly, you should try to let them know as soon as possible -- I would think, more than just a month in advance! And second, you should be careful about your reason. It's generally advised not to make it about the university or the department; things that they can change.

  For example, don't say: "I haven't been getting along with my colleagues here and I feel the university is not supporting me enough financially." That will make them feel defensive, and in the worst case, it could leave them thinking that they could have retained you if you had only talked to them earlier, and you could have worked something out.

  Instead, it's generally more effective to make your leaving *not about them.* It can be the university location, or personal/family constraints, or you simply have decided that academia is not for you. Since you want to remain friendly with your colleagues, you should be as honest as possible, without unnecessarily insulting them.

  For example: "While I have really enjoyed my time here, it's become increasingly clear to me that being in academia long-term is not the right fit. In addition, I have personal and family constraints that would require me to be away from  for extended periods of time, and make having a more flexible work location a necessity for me in the future. I have nothing but positive things to say about `<university>`. I'm sorry for the short notice; I'm letting you know as soon as possible, so that you can hopefully work to make plans accordingly for my departure."
- In the latter case, you have nothing to lose, so you can share some negative details about the department if you so choose, as long as you are careful in expressing it. In this case, you can also choose to leave on short notice (as long as it is allowed by your contract); it may upset them, but at the end of the day, you have to do what's best for you.

Comment: Very helpful comments. Thanks a lot. Yes the location and family situation is part of my reasoning.  Also for sure, I would want to keep things clean and make as little trouble as it's possible to stay in good terms. They new company directly works with the same school and the department I'm in right now.

Answer (score 2):

You have a contract and it may detail the requirements here. If you are teaching then you should give the head enough notice that they can replace you without negative impacts on students. If you have thesis advisees you need to consider their needs, ethically, if not necessarily legally.

Quitting, but continuing to end of term is likely to be fine, though the head may need to scramble to fill any teaching slots for next term.

Other than consideration for students who will be impacted I don't see a lot of issues, provided that your contract isn't too restrictive.

If your pay is pro-rated in any way, then some adjustments might need to be made but probably more likely in your favor than otherwise.

For the administrative details a month seems reasonable. For student and especially advisee outcomes it might be more complicated.

Comment: I have a postdoc that his contract ends in 3 months and he is now only at the stage of writing papers and one PhD student that JUST started . I have talked with one faculty that he is happy to have the student to work with him. I have also mentioned few times to the chair about things that are not working well for me in the department.

Comment: Try to assure the doctoral student is amenable to a change.

Comment: @Para2x Too late now, but you really shouldn't be recruiting PhD students when you're looking for jobs outside academia.

Comment: I totally understand. But truly the decision about the recruitment happened months before my decision for looking for job outside academia.

Comment: @BryanKrause I can understand the reasoning behind that, but I don't think management would have been very sympathetic if I'd taken that position when I was a faculty member.